# Could you use a chaotic pendulum to generate energy?

Tags: energy, kinematics, potential-energy

Could you use a chaotic pendulum to generate energy?

Comment: Not anymore than a regular pendulum. They work on the same principles.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. A pendulum only *stores* energy and cycles it back and forth between potential and kinetic forms as it swings. It does not pull energy out of nowhere. If you extract the energy from a swinging pendulum, it will stop swinging when the energy is all gone.